# Javascript instead of mapping to an array, returning one value at a time instead of a list of data?

Tags: javascript, json, chart.js

Instead of mapping it into an array, is there a way to return a single value from each index of the array when the function is called? Because this array is dynamic, it will constantly have new data appending to this array. Hence this array will get larger.
Here is my code:

```
async function fetchTemperature(){
            const response = await fetch("sampleData.json");
            const data = await response.json();
            
            //finding temperature
            var temp = data.records.map(function(elem){
                return elem.Temperature;
            });
            console.log(temp); //returns an array instead of one value
        }
```

This is my JSON file:

```
    {
    "records": [
        {
            "People":2,
            "Temperature": 27,
            "Humidity": 65,
            "Date": "2021-03-16",
            "Time": "10:06"
        },
        {
            "People":3,
            "Temperature": 27,
            "Humidity": 61,
            "Date": "2021-03-16",
            "Time": "10:07"
        },
        {
            "People":5,
            "Temperature": 26,
            "Humidity": 62,
            "Date": "2021-03-16",
            "Time": "10:08"
        },
        {
            "People":5,
            "Temperature": 26,
            "Humidity": 62,
            "Date": "2021-03-16",
            "Time": "10:08"
        },
        {
            "People":5,
            "Temperature": 28,
            "Humidity": 65,
            "Date": "2021-03-16",
            "Time": "10:09"
        },
        {
            "People":5,
            "Temperature": 28,
            "Humidity": 65,
            "Date": "2021-03-16",
            "Time": "10:09"
        }
        
    ]
}
```

My desire output is:

```
> fetchTemperature()
> 27
> fetchTemperature()
> 27
> fetchTemperature()
> 26
```

Comment: what is your desired output?

Comment: Yes, you can just return one, but which one would you like to return, random one, first one, last one.  The average of all temperatures..  It's a tad unclear what your asking.

Comment: Maybe what you want is a callback function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

then you need to define a global variable (`idx` for instance) to iterate through this temp array. then update idx value every time you call this method.

```
let idx = 0 

async function fetchTemperature () {
  const response = await fetch('sampleData.json')
  const data = await response.json()

  //finding temperature
  var temp = data.records.map(function (elem) {
    return elem.Temperature
  })
  console.log(temp[idx]) //returns an array instead of one value
  
  idx = (idx+1)%temp.length
}
```

Answer (score 0):

map returns an array.
So using join and passing the new line character as the delimitter can output what you want.

```
async function fetchTemperature(){
            const response = await fetch("sampleData.json");
            const data = await response.json();
            
            //finding temperature
            var temp = data.records.map(function(elem){
                return elem.Temperature;
            });
           console.log(temp.join('\r\n'));
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The console.log should be inside the map function to get 1 temperature for line if that is what you need.